# cannot implicitly convert type 'newtonsoft.json.linq.jtoken' to newt 'newtonsoft.json.linq.jvalue'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing a web api using visual studio, my post api should read the value from the body and return an array from the database, but I get the error listed in the title.

Here is my code:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult getsub([FromBody] JObject data)
    {

        using (GaminBrainEntities entities = new GaminBrainEntities())
        {
            JValue id = data.SelectToken("pk");
            return Ok(entities.SP_Brands_Get_By_Category(id).ToArray);
        }
    }
```

How can I change my code to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

return type of SelectToken method is JToken and it is not implicitly converted from JToken to JValue so this error throws by compiler, so change the type of id to JToken then compiler will be happy.

```
JToken id = data.SelectToken("");
```

and also your return statement throw error because of ToArray is method so you have to write ToArray() with bracket.this will solve your another error.if your id is integer value then first convert it to integer then pass it to stored procedure.

```
int idValue= id.ToObject<int>();

return Ok(entities.SP_Brands_Get_By_Category(idValue).ToArray());
```

Comment: i did it, but then i got another compiler error in return Ok(entities.SP_Brands_Get_By_Category(id).ToArray);

Comment: cannot convert from newtonsoft.json.linq.jtoken to long, for the "id" in stored procedure

Comment: what is the value comes in id? if it convertable in long then you have to first convert it into long by explicitly then pass it to stored procedure

Comment: i have edited my answer please check and try this it will solved your error. and use try catch to handle exception

Comment: i was using the same code in vb and worked fine for me, i don't know why is that happening in c#

Comment: because of syntax changes between c# and vb
have you tried,suggested changes in your code?

Comment: still not working, the suggesting is asking me to change the function itself to accept jtoken as parameter which is wrong

Comment: have you converted it to integer from JToken?

Comment: argument 1:cannot convert type 'newtonsoft.json.linq.jtoken' to Long

Comment: is this error throws from this line int idValue= id.ToObject<int>();?

Comment: no, from the last line where i place it in the stored procedure

Comment: are you sure you are passing idValue in store procedure instead of id?

Comment: yes, but i don't think the problem is from converting to long

Comment: can you share your stored procedure parameter data types?

Comment: bigint, my dear I don't know why this happening with me

Comment: even i changed the type to int or whatever, won't work, something else is blocking it

Comment: then without debugging I can not help you